# python @property, does not work properly in my machine

Tags: python, python-2.7, properties

```
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temperature = 0):
        self._temperature = temperature

    def to_fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.temperature * 1.8) + 32

    @property
    def temperature(self):
        print("Getting value")
        return self._temperature

    @temperature.setter
    def temperature(self, value):
        if value < -273:
            raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible")
        print("Setting value")
            self._temperature = value

c = Celsius()
c.temperature = -300
print c.temperature
```

I have code above, when execute it, should raise a ValueError exception. But anyway, I successfully run whole code and get output of -300. Anyone could help on this, appreciated.

Comment: You need to inherit from `object`, `property` setters and deleters only work with a new-style class.

Comment: Note that also, you should 1. be consistent on using `print` without parentheses (or, better yet, migrate to 3.x); and 2. set `self.temperature` in `__init__`, so that the setter isn't bypassed.